# Как отключить перемещение яндекс карты на мобильном?

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api, карты, yandex-maps-embed

Есть созданная карта с метками, с конструктора соответственно вставляю кусок кода

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" async src="https://api-maps.yandex.ru/services/constructor/1.0/js/?um=constructor%3A5a1ae2bdec74996aa0978e3d2e2ab5de3fb435e6281be0ef1fbc1&amp;width=100%25&amp;height=300&amp;lang=ru_UA&amp;scroll=false"></script>
```

Не получается убрать перемещение на мобильном устройстве, метод я нашел:
myMap.behaviors.disable('drag');

а вот как конкретно его реализовать, как добавить в скрипт ?

Answer (score 0):

Карты Конструктора нельзя модифицировать через JavaScript API, код виджета можно использовать только как есть со всеми дефолтными поведениями.

Если критично, чтобы на мобильном перетаскивание карты было отключено, можно экспортировать объекты карты из Конструктора в файл geoJSON или KML и создать карту с этими объектами через JS API.

Файлы в формате KML можно загружать в API с помощью [Geo XML](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/dg/concepts/geoxml-docpage/?from=SO) методом load:

```
ymaps.geoXml.load('<ссылка на файл доступный через интернет>')
```

В песочнице API Яндекс.Карт [есть пример](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/geoxml_display?from=SO)